# null и undefined - практические примеры

Tags: javascript

Вопрос таков: в `JavaScript` есть  свойства `null` и `undefined`, которые являются двумя разными объектами, но равны между собой. Ну так зачем же в `JS` присутствует и то и другое, какие реальные практические полезности это дает?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> в JavaScript есть свойства null и undefined, которые являются двумя разными объектами, но равны между собой

бред!

- null и undefined - примитивные значения
- они не являются объектами
- они не равны между собой

если тип переменной равен `undefined`, следовательно переменная не имеет значения вообще, как будто и не была объявлена, а `null` - это всего лиш ссылка в никуда, но ссылка, т.е. какое-то значение, его можно использовать например для того, чтобы пометить объект, который должен быть уничтожен GC

> Ну так зачем же в JS присутствует и то и другое

в JS много чего есть, чья практическая ценность крайне мала, тот же оператор `typeof`, который можно использовать всё для того же сравнения с `undefined` для всего остального он мало пригоден

- [Основы и заблуждения насчет JavaScript](http://habrahabr.ru/post/120193/)

Comment: но ко всему вышесказанному следует добавить:

    var a=null,b;
    alert(a==null);//true
    alert(b==null);//true;

В качестве "практической" ценности:

    $.extend(true,{foo:'bar'},{foo:null});//{foo:null}
    $.extend(true,{foo:'bar'},{foo:undefined});//{foo:'bar'}

Comment: использовать нестрогое сравнение в данном случае не очень верно, т.к. значение null и undefined будут одинаково неявно приведены к false

и ещё вопрос, почему использовали именно глубокое копирование с помощью extend?

Comment: @Spectre, нестрогое сравнение как раз для случая когда не важна разница между null и undefined, т.е. проверка на необходимость действий при незаполненном/отсутствующем значении.  
по поводу extend, привычка на самом деле, тут это не нужно, но если объекты будут иметь свойства-объекты будет передача ссылки... дую на воду в общем.

Answer (score 2):

Они не равны, сравнение покажет false:

```
alert( null === undefined );
```

Разница, например, в том, что если объект или его свойство существуют, то они могут быть равны null. Но - не undefined. Иными словами, null - это значение объекта, а проверка на undefined показывает само существование объекта в принципе.

Comment: Я понимаю в чем разница. Вопрос в том, какая практическая полезность.

Comment: >они могут быть равны null. Но - не undefined

    var obj = {prop : 'value'};
    obj.prop = void 0;
    obj => {prop: undefined} ?

Comment: Я имел в виду, что равны null, если существуют в принципе :)